# How do I make the observe function work more than once?

Tags: swiper.js

I'm trying to create a slider that will update every time a slide is altered. I've got it set to observe, observeParents, and observeChildren, and it works the first time I show or hide slides, but it's only working once. Is there a good workaround for this?

[Here's a link to the page with the slider on it.](https://serman-brands-inc.myshopify.com/products/the-elite-in-melted-chocolate) Click the color swatches to see what I'm talking about. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your link example is broken + Hard to understand your issue. Try to use SWIPER API events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround! I added a data-element called `data-slides` that updates on the container when you click to make the slideshow change, like so.

```
thumbnails.each(function() {
                var wrapper = $(this);
                container = $('.swiper-container');
                color = colorLabel.val();

                while (wrapper.parent().children().length === 1) {
                    wrapper = wrapper.parent();
                }

                if (jQuery(this).attr('alt') === optionValue) {
                    wrapper.fadeIn('500').show();
                    container.attr('data-slides', color);
                } else {
                    wrapper.fadeOut('500').hide();
                }
            });
```

It triggers the observe function and allows it to update as necessary.